# Spotting the linearly independent eigen vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

Hi all, I wanted to ask how complete part 1 of this **past exam question.** Considering the number of marks allocated to part 1, it seems that there is some sort of shortcut to get all six vectors

Comment: Your columns are all unit vectors

Comment: Im not sure what to do with this. I know that those columns aren't all 6 eigenvectors

Comment: Why do you think that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\renewcommand\bm\boldsymbol
$$

Let $\bm e_j$ be the $j$th unit column vector, i.e. the column vector with all entries $0$ except the $j$th one being $1$. Then
$$
\bm {Ce}_1 = \bm e_2, \bm {Ce}_2 = \bm e_1, \bm {Ce}_3 = \bm e_4, \bm {Ce}_4 = \bm e_3, \bm {Ce}_5 = \bm e_6, \bm {Ce}_6 = \bm e_5.
$$
**By observation**
$$
\bm C (\bm e_j \pm \bm e_{j+1}) =\bm e_{j+1} \pm \bm e_j\quad [j =1,3,5]
$$
and hence the eigenvectors are $\bm e_j \pm \bm e_{j+1}$ for $j = 1,3,5$, and the corresponding  eigenvalues are $1,-1, 1, -1, 1, -1$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix is block diagonal, so you can analyze each block separately. All three blocks are identical, so once you’ve found eigenvectors for one of them, generating similar-looking eigenvectors for the rest of the blocks should be trivial.

The problem is now reduced to finding a pair of linearly-independent eigenvectors for $$\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ The row sums are obviously the same, so you have $(1,1)^T$ as an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$ (the sum). The matrix is symmetric, so $(-1,1)$ is also an eigenvector—it’s orthogonal to the first one.

So, a set of six linearly-independent eigenvectors of the original matrix is $(\pm1,1,0,0,0,0)^T$, $(0,0,\pm1,1,0,0)^T$ and $(0,0,0,0,\pm1,1)^T$.

Comment: I am trying to get the reasoning behind - after analysing the small block how we can put the vectors for the small blaock and then associate zeros to get the eigen vectors of the  whole matrix, why this always works with the block matrices?

Comment: @BAYMAX The blocks correspond to a direct sum decomposition of the domain just as do the blocks in the Jordan normal form of a matrix: the first block in your matrix only affects the span of $\mathbf e_1$ and $\mathbf e_2$, and so on. You can also think of it in terms of the definition of matrix multiplcation: $A\mathbf v$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$ with coefficients given by $\mathbf v$. If there’s a $0$ in row $i$ of column $j$, that column contributes nothing to row $i$ of the result.

Comment: Cool! thanks for your explanation!